# Why can we not overload operators for fundamental data types in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, primitive-types

Why can we not overload operators for fundamental data types in C++, but we can for user defined classes?

Comment: Do you have a particular use case in mind where overloading operators for built-in types would make things better? Aside, if this isn't answered in D&E, it's likely too opinionated, but I wouldn't be able to tell you if the creator himself answered this.

Comment: What "fundamental classes" are you referring to?

Comment: @chris Sometimes I wish I could make `^` mean "power" instead of XOR when working with numeric types - or redefine `/` to prevent unhandled divide-by-zero errors (when its acceptable to return 0 in that case).

Comment: The operations performed on fundamental types are already well defined. It would be a serious mind <expletive deleted> for `1+1` to do anything but sum to 2.

Comment: I'll suggest a workaround by interpreting input string and translate to calculated result. Eg: "1+3^2" = interpreted as 10. There should be some 3rd party arithmetic expression to actual numeric result libraries.

Comment: Please explain why you need this.